# Filter gallery by one column or another

Tags: powerapps

I have a gallery with the following properties:

Referenced SharePoint list: 'Project Dashboard"

Variable: CurrentUser - this is set to User().email

Relevant columns in 'Project Dashboard' are submitter and executive sponsor

I can filter the gallery using this: Filter('Project Dashboard', Submitter=CurrentUser) and it works great, however I have been asked to now include results if the CurrentUser is listed under the 'Executive Sponsor' column as well. When I write this out it says invalid argument so I'm sure that I'm just using the OR function wrong.

Filter('Project Dashboard', Submitter=CurrentUser || 'Executive Sponsor'=CurrentUser)

Please let me know if you have any ideas for how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure you don't have any typos.
2. Try using `in` or `exactin` in place of `=`

You could also try the long hand code:

```
Filter(
    'Project Dashboard', 
    Or(
        Submitter=CurrentUser,
        'Executive Sponsor'=CurrentUser
    )
)
```

Comment: I wrote that out and it's still throwing the "Invalid Argument" error. It underlines the "=" between 'Executive Sponsor' and CurrentUser. I'm wondering if maybe the filter just doesn't have support for or statements, although the or statement isn't what's throwing the error...

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Unfortunately, that didn't work either, now it's giving the error on whatever is to the right of the "in" or "exactin".

Comment: Need screenshots and details if you want more help!